# How to execute t4 template using the Cake script

Tags: c#, continuous-integration, t4, cakebuild

What is the API / Syntax to execute the `T4 template` using the `Cake build`? Any example code will be helpful.

Whether [StartProcess](https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common/ProcessAliases/C40DC6C0) API should be used to call the `texttransform.exe` or is there any other API's available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's two built-in aliases for working with [T4 templates](https://cakebuild.net/dsl/text/#T4-Text-Templating) in Cake, 
[TransformTemplate(ICakeContext, FilePath)](https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Tools.TextTransform/TextTransformAliases/C5034268) and 
[TransformTemplate(ICakeContext, FilePath, TextTransformSettings)](https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Tools.TextTransform/TextTransformAliases/70A7C1EA)

Example usage:

```
#tool "nuget:?package=Mono.TextTransform&version=1.0.0"

Task("TransformTemplate")
    .Does(() => {
    var templateFile = File("./Template.tt");

    TransformTemplate(templateFile);
});


RunTarget("TransformTemplate");
```

Example template used

```
Template generated <#=DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")#>
```

Example template result

```
Template generated 2020-02-12 11:19:08
```

If you have .NET Core installed it's recommended that you use the [dotnet-t4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotnet-t4/) global tool as it's more well maintained.

Example cake script using the [dotnet-t4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotnet-t4/) global tool (Cake tool resolution will find use either t4.exe or texttransform.exe automatically depending on which it finds first, as with any tool you can override which tool used by [ToolSettings](https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Core.Tooling/ToolSettings/) [ToolPath](https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Core.Tooling/ToolSettings/F6956DA8) property in this case [TextTransformSettings](https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Tools.TextTransform/TextTransformSettings/)

```
#module nuget:?package=Cake.DotNetTool.Module&version=0.4.0
#tool "dotnet:?package=dotnet-t4&version=2.0.5"

Task("TransformTemplate")
    .Does(() => {
    var templateFile = File("./HelloWorld.tt");
    var targetFile = File("./HelloWorld.txt");
    var settings = new TextTransformSettings {
                    OutputFile = targetFile,
                    Properties = {
                        ["FirstName"] = "John",
                        ["LastName"] = "Doe"
                    }
                };


    TransformTemplate(templateFile, settings);
});


RunTarget("TransformTemplate");
```

Example `HelloWorld.tt`

```
<#@ parameter name='FirstName' #>
<#@ parameter name='LastName' #>
Hello <#=FirstName#> <#=LastName#>!
```

Example result `HelloWorld.txt`

```
Hello John Doe!
```

To use `Cake.DotNetTool.Module` we atm need to bootstrap so module is fetched from NuGet (won't be needed in Cake 1.0), example execution

```
dotnet cake .\t4.cake --bootstrap 
dotnet cake .\t4.cake
```

As asked for below an example using directive processor(Note: in mono T4 this is depreciated, so will only fully work with VisualStudio version of TextTransform.exe), directive processors aren't currently wrapped in [TextTransformSettings](https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Tools.TextTransform/TextTransformSettings/) but we can sort it like any Cake tool through [ToolSettings](https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Core.Tooling/ToolSettings/)  [ArgumentCustomization](https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Core.Tooling/ToolSettings/50AAB3A8) property.

Example template `DirectiveTemplate.tt`

```
<#@template language="c#" hostspecific="true"#>
Hello <#= this.Host.ResolveParameterValue("", "", "greet") #>!
```

Example Cake script, where we use VSWhere to locate VisualStudio version of `TextTransform.exe`, register path with Cake tool resolution and pass directive argument through argument customization.

```
#tool "nuget:?package=vswhere&version=2.8.4"

Setup(setupContext =>{
    DirectoryPath vsLatest = VSWhereLatest();
    FilePath    textTransformPath = vsLatest?.CombineWithFilePath("Common7/IDE/TextTransform.exe");

    if (textTransformPath == null || !FileExists(textTransformPath))
    {
        throw new Exception("Failed to resolve TextTransform.exe path.");
    }

    setupContext.Tools.RegisterFile(textTransformPath);
});


Task("T4")
    .Does(() => {
    var settings = new TextTransformSettings {
                    ArgumentCustomization = args => args.AppendSwitchQuoted("-a", " ", "!!greet!John")
                };
    TransformTemplate("./DirectiveTemplate.tt", settings);
});

RunTarget("T4");
```

The result in `DirectiveTemplate.txt` will be

```
Hello John!
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will check whether it will work for my requirements.

Comment: Ok! Please mark as answered if it answers your question or update question with more context if it doesn't provide what you we're looking for.

Comment: It will be helpful if provided an additional example on how to pass arguments to the tt file.

Comment: Hmm, the HelloWorld.tt template has parameters or were you thinking of something else.

Comment: Consider the first example `Template.tt` , I want to apply parameters to this template.  Consider the example : 

`texttransform.exe "Template1.tt" -a "!!foo1!bar1" -a "!!foo2!bar2"`. 

I want to achieve this in the cake build.

Comment: Sure directives are not supported by all versions of TextTransform.exe, it's not currently typed in the settings class, but certainly possibe, I'll add an example.

Comment: Directive example added to answer.

Comment: Thanks again and providing the example for getting `texttransofrm.exe` path using `vswhere` is so helpful.